# how to programatically identify a file as a .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, asp.net

Is there a way to readily find the assemblies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How to programmatically determine if a
>   file is an assembly
>
> Call the GetAssemblyName method,
>   passing the full file path and name of
>   the file you are testing.
>
> If a BadImageFormatException exception
>   is thrown, the file is not an
>   assembly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173100.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Jeff's suggestion, there appears to be a method to test if an assembly is managed without throwing an exception documented here: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=424454

> Actually, if you open a .NET Library / Application in a binary editor, you will see that the ASCI text "BSJB" is shortly followed by the version of the Framework that the DLL / EXE needs.
>
> So, depending on the presence of this search attribute, you can not only identify whether the library / executible is a managed library, but also the version of the Framework it uses.

Comment: DON'T DO STUFF LIKE THIS. It is not guaranteed to work in any way, shape or form in the future.

Comment: If you read further down that same page, there are better ways documented as well. In addition, I find your all caps statement rather annoying. Some hacks such as this one can be used to good benefit in combination with a fail-safe. The number of assemblies being checked by the OP probably doesn't warrant a second thought, but in case it does, it's always good to try to avoid relying on exceptions as a part of normal process flow. If the assembly can be checked faster using a hack first, why not try it?

Comment: +1 just because this works on the command line, `FINDSTR /M /S "BSJB" *.dll` will produce a list of all .Net dlls in a folder

Answer (score 1):

Call [`AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.getassemblyname.aspx) and see whether it throws an exception.